# Sharepoint 2013 only to use cubes for dashboards or tables as well?

Tags: sql-server-2012, dashboard-designer-2013

We have some SSRS reports pulled directly from datamart tables, we are not using SSAS cubes. This is SQL Server 2012. 
Now we are implemented a Sharepoint 2013 solution and we will use it for dashboards.

My question is:
For this, can Sharepoint ONLY read cubes? Or can it make dashboards also from the datamart tables?
I would like to know if IT IS POSSIBLE to use Sharepoint for dashboards directly from the tables (despite best practices, etc).

Thanks a lot